# left parenthesis is printed in postfix & right parenthesis error

Tags: java, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation, evaluate

This program should convert the infix into postfix and evaluate the postfix using ArrayStack.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Postfix {
  //Infix expression string
  public static String infix;

  //Postfix expression string
  public static String postfix; 

  //Top of operatorStack
  public static char topOperator;

  /**Converts an infix expression to postfix expression*/
  public static String convertToPostfix(String infix) {

    //Create operatorStack ArrayStack that contain character elements
    StackInterface<Character> operatorStack = new ArrayStack(infix.length());

    //Initialize a new empty postfix string
    StringBuilder postfix = new StringBuilder();

    //While the infix string still has character
    for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++) {
        char nextCharacter = infix.charAt(i);

        switch (nextCharacter) {
            case '+' : case '-' : case '*' : case '/' : 
                        // stack is not empty if infix expression is valid
                        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && (getPrecedence(nextCharacter) <= getPrecedence(operatorStack.peek()))) {
                            postfix.append(operatorStack.peek());
                            operatorStack.pop();
                        }
                        operatorStack.push(nextCharacter);
                break;
            case '(' : operatorStack.push(nextCharacter);
                break;
            case ')' : topOperator = operatorStack.pop();
                        while (topOperator != '(') {
                            postfix.append(topOperator);
                            topOperator = operatorStack.pop();
                        }
                break;
            default  : postfix.append(nextCharacter);
                break;
        }
    }

    //While operatorStack is not empty
    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
        topOperator = operatorStack.pop();
        postfix.append(topOperator);
    }
    return postfix.toString();
}

 /**Determine the precedence of operator*/
private static int getPrecedence(char operator) { 
    if (operator == '(' || operator == ')' ) 
        return 3;
    else if (operator == '/' || operator == '*')
        return 2;
    else if (operator == '+' || operator == '-')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

/**Evaluates a postfix expression*/
public static int evaluatePostfix(String postfix) {
    //Create an empty Integer valueStack that contain the integer element 
    StackInterface<Integer> valueStack = new ArrayStack(postfix.length());

     int operandTwo; 
     int operandOne;

    //While the postfix string still has character
    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
        char nextCharacter = postfix.charAt(i);

             if ( Character.isDigit(nextCharacter)) 
                 valueStack.push(nextCharacter - 48);
             else if (nextCharacter == '+' || nextCharacter == '-' || nextCharacter == '*' || nextCharacter == '/') {

                 operandTwo = Integer.parseInt(valueStack.pop().toString());

                 operandOne = Integer.parseInt(valueStack.pop().toString());

                 switch (nextCharacter) {
                  case '+' : valueStack.push(operandOne + operandTwo); 
                    break;
                  case '-' : valueStack.push(operandOne - operandTwo); 
                    break;
                  case '*' : valueStack.push(operandOne * operandTwo); 
                    break;
                  case '/' : valueStack.push(operandOne / operandTwo); 
                    break;
                 } // End switch
             } // End else loop
    } //End for loop
    return  valueStack.peek();
}

/**Main method*/
public static void main(String args[]){

    //Create a Scanner object 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Infix to Postfix Converter");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");

    //Prompt user to input the infix expression
    System.out.print("\nPlease type an infix expression "
            + "\n[Digit used are between 1 to 9] : ");
    String infixExp = input.nextLine();

    //Convert infix expression into postfix
    String postfixExp = convertToPostfix(infixExp);

    //Print the infix expression
    System.out.println("\n\tInfix expression   : " + infixExp);

    //Print the postfix expression
    System.out.println("\tPostfix expression : " + postfixExp);

    //Calculate and print evaluated value
    System.out.println("\t\tValue\t   = " + evaluatePostfix(postfixExp));
 }

}
```

I can get the right postfix if the infix expression does not has parenthesis.
But, if I put complete parenthesis, for example, `(1+1)`, I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stack is empty.
>       at A.ArrayStack.pop(ArrayStack.java:24)
>       at A.Postfix.convertToPostfix(Postfix.java:42)
>       at A.Postfix.main(Postfix.java:120)

If I just put the left parenthesis '(', it will be printed in the postfix. Like `1+1*(6`, the postfix output is `116(*+:`

```
Infix to Postfix Converter
--------------------------

Please type an infix expression 
[Digit used are between 1 to 9] : 1+1*(6

Infix expression   : 1+1*(6
Postfix expression : 116(*+
    Value      = 7
```

Here is the generic StackInterface class:

```
public interface StackInterface<T> {
//Adds a new object to the top of stack.
public void push(T object);

//Removes and returns the stack top entry.
/*If the stack is empty before the operation, null */
public T pop();

//Retrieves the stack top entry.
/*If the stack is empty before the operation, null */
public T peek();

//Return true if the stack is empty.
public boolean isEmpty();

//Removes all entries from the stack.
public void clear();

}
```

And here is the ArrayStack class:

```
public class ArrayStack implements StackInterface {
//Array of stack entries
private Object[] stack;

//Size of stack
private int size;

//Create stack with initial capacity
public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity) {
    stack = new Object[initialCapacity];
}

//Adds an object to the top of stack.
public void push(Object object) {
    if (size == stack.length) 
        resize();
    stack[size++] = object;
}

//Removes and returns the top of stack.
public Object pop() {
    if (size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty.");
    Object object = stack[--size];
    stack[size] = null;
    return object;
}

//Return the top of stack.
public Object peek() {
    if (size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty.");
    return stack[size-1];
}

//Check if stack is empty
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (size == 0);
}

//Resize array stack 
private void resize() {
    Object[] tempStack = stack;
    stack = new Object[2 * tempStack.length];
    System.arraycopy(tempStack, 0, stack, 0, size);
}

//Clear the stack
public void clear() {
    while(!isEmpty())
        pop();  
}
}
```

I assume that the first problem seem to be at

```
public Object pop() {
    if (size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty.");
    Object object = stack[--size];
    stack[size] = null;
    return object;
}
```

Could someone find the solution? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a lot of code. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: The debug shows that the problem is in the ArrayStack class:    public Object pop() { if (size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty.");

Comment: What is _the debug_? I mean step through your code with a debugger or pen and paper and see what happens with your values.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here:

when you have string like (1+1)

When you encounter "+", you pop the "(" and push "+" using below:

```
while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && (getPrecedence(nextCharacter) <= getPrecedence(operatorStack.peek()))) {
                        postfix.append(operatorStack.peek());
                        operatorStack.pop();
}
```

So in operator stack you just have "+"
when you encounter last ")" at that time in your operator stack you have "+"

```
 case ')' : topOperator = operatorStack.pop(
               while (topOperator != '(') {
                        postfix.append(topOperator);
                        topOperator = operatorStack.pop();
                    }
            break;
```

you are trying to pop "+" which is perfect but in your while loop again you try to pop which is where you get stack empty exception. Why dont you peer in case ')' and then loop in while?